# What does each line of this code do?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm new to Javascript coding and I've come across this TryIt page on w3schools. I understand that the code creates two buttons, which turn a bulb on and off when clicked, but I'd like some more detailed explanation from some Javascript experts on what each line in this code exactly does.

For example, does

```
<button onclick="document.getElementById('myImage').src='pic_bulbon.gif'">
```

just create a button and make the image titled bulbon.gif appear when clicked? I'm slightly confused. Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>What Can JavaScript Do?</h2>

<p>JavaScript can change HTML attributes.</p>

<p>In this case JavaScript changes the src (source) attribute of an image.    </p>

<button onclick="document.getElementById('myImage').src='pic_bulbon.gif'">Turn on the light</button>

<img id="myImage" src="pic_bulboff.gif" style="width:100px">

<button onclick="document.getElementById('myImage').src='pic_bulboff.gif'">Turn off the light</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Both the buttons just change the source attribute of image. Nothing else.

Comment: You should separate your JavaScript from HTML. Use external JavaScript and CSS as a best practice.

Answer (score 0):

Let's have a look at the code :

> onclick="document.getElementById('myImage').src='pic_bulbon.gif'"

`OnClick` bind an event on the button, which will be fired when the button is clicked.
There are various events, depending on the kind of element you are using. Like, onKeyUp, onKeyDown, onSelect etc

`document.getElementById('myImage')` tells the browser to retrieve the DOM element which ID is "myImage" (/!\ remember IDs must be unique in your code, if not the behaviour is unknown and your code won't work as expected. getElementsByName will give back an array with the DOM elements matching the given name. People tend to be confused between the 2 functions, yet pay attention at the ending S: getElement/getElements)

`.src = "pic_bulbon.gif"` replace the previously found element source with the new picture and so force the redraw of that element.

So, no it does not create a new element but change the property of an existing one